# How to hide Home menu item Joomla 3.x?

Tags: joomla, menu

How can I hide the "Home" menu item Joomla 3.x? Home page must be Default Page and accessible by clicking on site-icon in header.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new menu, call it hidden (or whatever) to indicate it is not displayed, and add your home menu item to this menu. Then, in administrator->modules simply make sure this menu module is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Second way to solve it:

```
.nav-collapse > .menu > li:first-child 
   { 
   display: none; 
}
```